# Disable preview Images

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Sorry, I need to disable preview images. Not only *not view preview* (that I try with success with disableImageLoad: true) but also disable the action of client-side.

I need to save time by disabling this.

Thank you.

Comment: could you please post the source you tried here ,

Comment: I try this: $('#fileupload').fileupload(
 'option', {
        disableImageLoad: true
        }
 );

Answer (score 0):

I try this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload( 'option', { disableImageLoad: true } );
```

But however the app works

[image: see image]